# nspredicate multiple OR conditions

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm trying to fetch RLMObjects based on Type property of the RLMObject.

Here are the few predicate string I tried, some worked and some didn't :

```
 @"location = 'Canada' and Type = 'Call'"                     //works well

 @"location = 'Canada' and Type = 'Call' or Type = 'Meeting'" //failed

 @"location = 'Canada' and Type = 'Call' or Type = 'Meeting' or Type = 'Reminder'" //failed
```

Why the last two predicate strings failed ?

Comment: `@"location = 'Canada' and (Type = 'Call' or Type = 'Meeting')"` ? Same as if you write simple an `if` test with `&&` and `||`

Comment: got it worked! Thanks @Larme